# "Cannot load module" error when using NMS

Tags: nms

We have a problem with NMS monitoring application.
(NMS is a monitoring application for banking transaction. It owns [Ingenico](https://www.ingenico.com)). Because of an accident our server broke and since then, when we install NMS on the server, Apache doesn't run and gives us this error:

```
>>> httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 26 of C:/nms/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/nms/php/php5apache2_2.dll into server: The specified module could not be found.
```